# IBOutlet UIView loaded from a Nib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am loading a UIView from a NIB file with outlets and I want to change the properties of these outlets. I am wondering when I should do that because in the init method the outlets are nil and that make sense and in the drawRect method I can change the properties of my outlets but I'm not sure it's the proper way to do that.
Is there a method called after the init method and the drawRect method where I could do what I want ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's layoutSubviews - this will definitely be called before the first call to drawRect?

Answer (score 3):

The `UIViewController` method `viewDidLoad` is called after a nib has been loaded and after `loadView` is called. (`loadView` allows you to load a view programmatically instead of using a nib. However, nibs are much better so it's best to pretend that `loadView` doesn't exist.)

`NSObject` implements `awakeFromNib`. `awakeFromNib` is called after an object has been loaded from a nib. Here's a quote from the docs:

> Typically, you implement awakeFromNib for objects that require additional set up that cannot be done at design time. For example, you might use this method to customize the default configuration of any controls to match user preferences or the values in other controls. You might also use it to restore individual controls to some previous state of your application.

`drawRect:` is a `UIView` method, only use it if you need to do Quartz drawing. Using layers and Core Animation is more efficient. If you want to configure a custom `UIView` (i.e. you've subclassed `UIView` instead of configuring a view within a `UIViewController`) then you should use `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: That's only inside a UIViewController - the question mentions loading a UIView :)

Comment: Yes deanWombourne is right. Moreover in initWithCoder my outlet views are still nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IBOutlets in your initialization code for a UIView - override awakeFromNib. This is the first method called after outlets have been configured.

With regard to UIViewController - viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear are often convenient locations to put your initialization code in but beware: autolayout has not happened at this stage which means strange autoresizing effects can cause you bother. The better solution is to put your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews which is the first lifecycle method called after autolayout.